# How to export from x,y,z to geotiff using python

Tags: python

I have code in python to open a netcdf and export x,y, concetration. How can i make from this variables x,y, concetration a geotiff using python?

Thank you in advance

Code is the followig:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import uniform, seed
from osgeo import gdal, osr, gdal_array
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
import sys
import scipy
from scipy import interpolate,misc

from scipy.interpolate import griddata,RegularGridInterpolator
in_filename='E:/Ioannis_MarineEO_Task1/03_Dati_CMEMS/arctic/20190130_dm-metno-MODEL-topaz4-ARC-b20190129-fv0/20190130_dm-metno-MODEL-topaz4-ARC-b20190129-fv02.0.nc'
var_name='salinity'

error_code=0
#Open netCDF file with gdal 
src_ds=gdal.Open(in_filename)


subdataset='NETCDF:"'+in_filename+'":'+var_name    


#Read data using xarray
xr_ensemble = xr.open_dataset(in_filename)
data = xr_ensemble[var_name]
print ('Properties of the variable to be exported is: '+str((data)))
data = np.ma.masked_array(data)
data=np.ma.getdata(data)
data1=np.asarray(data)

ncDataset = nc.Dataset(in_filename, 'r')
latit = ncDataset.variables["latitude"][:]

latit=np.ma.getdata(latit)
longi = ncDataset.variables["longitude"][:]

longi=np.ma.getdata(longi)

if np.ndim(data)<=3:
    data=data[0,:,:]
else:
    data=data[0,0,:,:]
var_data=[]
x=[]
y=[]
var_data=[]


for (i,j), value in np.ndenumerate(data1):
    if np.isnan(data1[i,j])==False:
        var_data.append(data1[i,j])
        x.append(longi[i,j])
        y.append(latit[i,j])


temp1=np.column_stack([x,y,var_data])
```

I open the data from the netcdf with xarray. With  netcdf i open y (latitude) and x (longitude). Then create lists where i have for every x,y,pixel_value. 
Then i want from the  points with x,y,pixel_value to create a geotif using python?

Comment: What have tried so far? What is the problem you're facing? Could you share your code?

Comment: The code is the following:

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it is very much convenient to use `rasterio` and `numpy` to make a geotiff from from netCDF4 objects. Assuming your netcdf file has 2d or 3d arrays, following can be done. You will require information like coverage of the geotiff, projection, resolution etc which will be assigned to the file.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np

fpath = 'E:/Ioannis_MarineEO_Task1/03_Dati_CMEMS/arctic/20190130_dm-metno-MODEL-topaz4-ARC-b20190129-fv0/20190130_dm-metno-MODEL-topaz4-ARC-b20190129-fv02.0.nc'

ds = nc.Dataset(fpath)
# Check file and dataset properties by printing it.
print(ds)

# Dimensions and time

for dim in ds.dimensions.values():
    print(dim)

print(ds['time'])
```

Variable details should provide minimum and maximum of latitude and longitude of your file.

```
# Varaible details 
for var in ds.variables.values():
    print(var)


ds_sal = ds['salinity']

# numpy array of your salinity data 
sal_array = np.array(ds_sal)

print(sal_array.shape) # This should provide information about height and 
                         #width to make geotiff.
```

Set origin as per your file's properties. For this example, I am considering the file contains global data coverage with Geographic projection with 0.05 degree resolution. Height and width of data to be 3600 and 7200 respectively.

```
# create geotiff using above array and rasterio

from rasterio.transform import Affine, from_origin

transform = from_origin(-180,90, 0.05, 0.05)

ds_tif = rio.open('netcdf_to_geotif.tiff',
                   'w',
                    driver = 'GTiff',
                    height = 3600,
                    width = 7200,
                    dtype = sal_array.dtype,
                    count = 1,
                    crs = 'EPSG:4326',
                    transform = transform)
ds_tif.write(sal_array, 1)
ds_tif.close()
```

Adjusting the extent and resolution as per your requirement, this should give a geotiff file.